# Extract entries from a list and store each one on a matrix

Tags: r, list

Okay, so I have the following list on R:

```
seg_sites      list[1000]       List of length 1000
 [[1]]       double [40x162]    00000000000000000000000...
 [[2]]       double [40x150]    11110000000000000000000...
 [[3]]       double [40x160]    00000000111111110000000...
 [[4]]       double [40x93]     00110000000000111100000...
 [[5]]       double [40x144]    00000110000000000110000...
  ...
```

And the list goes on for a thousand entries. As you can see, I always have the same number of rows but I have different number of columns for each entry. What I want to do, is extract each entry to a single matrix. For example, I want to create a matrix called "output_1" containing the information the [[1]] entry, then output_2 with the information from the [[2]] entry and so on.

I was trying to use a for loop for this:

```
# Loop to intialize the matrices where I want to store the different entries
for(i in 1:nrep) {
     output_single_i <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 40, ncol = ncol(single[["seg_sites"]][[i]]))
}

# Loop to actually store the different entries in each matrix 
for(i in 1:nrep) {  
  output_single_i <- matrix(single$seg_sites[[i]], ncol = ncol(single[["seg_sites"]][[i]]))
}
```

What this code is doing is just saving the last entry on the list on a matrix called "output_single_i" but I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the data in current form is easy to manipulate. Why do you bother to store each one seperately?

Comment: Yes, it's true that the data in the form of a list is easy to manipulate and that should be said. However, each entry on the list is a different simulation (of a situation in population genetics) and I want to compare and compute various statistics from each simulation

Comment: Are you sure you want to clutter your workspace with thousands of objects which are called `object_1`, `object_2`, and so on?

Comment: @Uwe Yes, I understand it will clutter the workspace and I will probably end up doing it another way but right now I just want to find out how it's possible to do this... Just for the sake of knowing it

Comment: @JoãoCarvalho you can keep the list as it is and loop through this list and extract summary statistics out of matrix data. To loop through the list, you can use `lapply()`

Answer (score 2):

we can use `assign` to create matrix data from a list of matrices. The matrix  data are saved in global environment, which you can inspect using `ls()`

```
invisible( lapply(seq_along(mylist), function(x) {
  assign( x = paste0("Output", x), value = mylist[[x]], envir = .GlobalEnv )
  return(TRUE)
  } ))
```

Another way is to use `list2env()` function

```
names(mylist) <- paste0( 'output', seq_along(mylist))
list2env( mylist, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Data:

```
mylist <- list(matrix(1:10, ncol = 5), matrix(1:10, ncol = 2))
    str(mylist)
    # List of 2
    # $ : int [1:2, 1:5] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    # $ : int [1:5, 1:2] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! However, and at least in my case, both of these solutions only create a list that is exactly the same as the list I had in the first place

Comment: `fortunes::fortune(236)`:

*The only people who should use the assign function are those who fully understand why you should
never use the assign function.
   -- Greg Snow
      R-help (July 2009)*

Comment: i see a list of matrices in the global environment. check it with `ls()`

Comment: @Uwe please provide a link to the Rhelp article, if possible. Thanks

Comment: Here you go: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-July/396426.html

Comment: @Uwe thanks for the link. I am just curious, do you see any problem in my answer other than populating the global environment with lot of variables?

Comment: @Sathish, Techinically speaking, no, But from a data processing perspective it indicates problems. The usage of `assign()` is only a symptom.

Comment: @Uwe Thanks for the comment.